# How to set Synaptics locked-dragging Timeout under Windows?

Tags: windows, timeout, drag-and-drop, synaptics-touchpad

I have Lenovo Ideapad Y510p with Synaptics Clickpad and running Windows 10. I like to have Locked-Dragging feature but Synaptics settings application only allow to either turn it On or Off. However, I want this feature to run with timeout (>0) so that it perform like this:

1. I tap once
2. Tap again immediately to start dragging
3. The drag even keeps going on while my finger is down
4. Once I raise my finger, the dragging even goes in standby for a specific time (timeout)

   - The drag continue if I put my finger back before timeout (without initiating the event gesture again)
   - The drag event is terminated if I did not put my finger back before timeout

The locked-drag timeout setting is available in Linux and I use it on my ubuntu but can't find how to do it in Windows. The settings application is not feature-rich so I assume I might need to tweak a couple of registry keys but I don't know which one (could not find one that is related).

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**PS1:** I had this problem with Windows 8/8.1 so it is a driver problem (or driver configuration) and not related to Windows 10.

**PS2:** The driver version is v19.0.9.5 which is the latest by Lenovo and was installed through Windows Update. The latest generic driver released to public by Synaptics itself is v17.0.19 and it does have the same problem.